# Is there anything to support this Wikipedia claim about Ursula K. Le Guin re-using the planet name "Werel"?

Tags: ursula-k-le-guin, hainish-cycle

Comments to Lorendiac's answer in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/202525/sf-novel-about-crashed-pilot) pointed out an odd coincidence -- [Ursula K. Le Guin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ursula_K._Le_Guin)  may have used the same planet name ("Werel") to refer to different worlds in different stories:

- The related 1960s novels *[Planet of Exile](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_of_Exile)* and *[City of Illusions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_Illusions)*
- The 1995 novella collection *[Four Ways to Forgiveness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Ways_to_Forgiveness)*

The Wikipedia article for *Four Ways to Forgiveness* claims

> This 'Werel' is not the same as the world called Werel in Le Guin's Planet of Exile and City of Illusions.

but there isn't any citation or explanation why.

Both novels are set in the "[Hainish Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hainish_Cycle)" universe and both involve liberation from slavery. In *PoEx* and *CoI* the Werelese are liberators but in *FWtF* they are the enslavers.

Is there any statement from LeGuin herself about any  relation (or lack thereof) between the Werels in the two story sets, or is it inferred only from the text?

Comment: As an aside, in any sufficiently realistic work planet names *will* be deliberately duplicated, for much the same reason there is, e.g., more than one city named Dover, only more so.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you follow the source linked in the Wikipedia article it quotes LeGuin with saying in an [open letter](http://digital.lib.usf.edu/content/SF/S0/02/45/13/00111/S67-00111-n225-1996-09_10.pdf#page=12) that she had "simply forgot" that she had used the name already. Also the planets are described differently. [Screenshot from Google Books](https://books.google.de/books?id=dQJMK8SeNmsC&pg=PA432&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false):

[image]

The book is: Erlich, Richard D. (2009). Coyote's Song: The Teaching Stories of Ursula K. Le Guin. Milford series: Popular writers of today. 72. Wildside Press. p. 432. ISBN 9781434457752.

Comment: I'm always loath to quote from preview-only Google Books sources, especially given LeGuin's fierce vocal opposition to what she perceived as Google's disregarding of copyright. It would be great to see the "Open Letter" itself.

Comment: @Spencer, personally I'd loathe to leave my wife's sick bed to drive home and pick the book from the shelf just so I can quote it first hand, so Google books is all that you'll get from me. I may understand your feelings about this, but that doesn't make the answer wrong.

Comment: @Eike You have my upvote but there's the matter of the  prudent 24-hour soak before accepting an answer (in addition to Valorum's providing a great source for an edit).

Comment: I would suggest quoting the text directly rather than just including a screenshot for accessibility reasons (I don't think screen readers can reliably interpret the text contained in an image), but there doesn't seem to be any easy way to copy that text from Google Books (and I can't find it anywhere else online) and it's not really feasible to retype the whole thing by hand. In contrast, it should be fairly easy to copy the text from the open letter PDF if you're okay with it (though there might be a few OCR errors that need to be corrected).

Comment: @V2Blast: Even if a screen reader *could* OCR the text, it *won't*, because the image's alt text is set to "enter image description here" (so that's what the screen reader will say).

Comment: @Spencer, sorry, my comment came out all wrong, didn't it? I just wanted to point out that I did not deprive any author of his royalties, since that seems to worry you. Google books was just a convenience while I am not at home.

Comment: Le Guin's own FAQ page (http://www.ursulakleguin.com/FAQ.html#BookOrder) says the same
"I have to warn you that the planet Werel in Four Ways is not the planet Werel in Planet of Exile. In between novels, I forget planets. Sorry."